# Colocar dados na mesma coluna (table) HTML5

Tags: html5, css3, tabela-html

Bom dia pessoal,

estou tentando colocar três imagens na mesma coluna, mas não estou conseguindo.

**Alguém saberia dizer qual o erro do meu código?**

Segue imagem de onde eu gostaria de colocar o dados e o código que estou utilizando.

[image: Tabela]

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="title">Pacientes</th>
           <th class="title">Como estou?</th>
           <th class="title">Administrar Paciente</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
           <td><?=$linha['name']?></td>
           <td> <?=$$linnha['item_key']?> </td>
           <td> <a href="viewPatient.html" id="viewPatient"> <img id="viewPatientIcon" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/eye-outline.png" alt="eye icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> </td>          
            <td> <a href="editPatient.html" id="editPatient"> <img id="editPatientIcon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/software-menu-icons/256/SoftwareIcons-68-512.png" alt="pen icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> </td>
            <td> <a href="deletePatient" id="deletePatient"> <img id="deletePatientIcon" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-coloricon/21/19-512.png" alt="delete icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onde está o while($linha... ou foreach($linha.. ?

Comment: Eu estou tentando formatar a visualização dos dados que puxo do banco via php.

Comment: Ola Laura, para sua pergunta, a resposta do @Alexandre Cavaloti, parece ser o suficiente para deixar as 3 imagens na mesma coluna. Vi que você está usando imagens da net, eu indico no lugar dessas imagens você usar os iconis, pode ser do bootstrap, ou [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free), para suas páginas, a não ser que seja um requisito do sistema usar essas imagens. Elas são mais leves e também bem fácil de implementar, no site tem a documentação. Experimente, caso já conheça e não usou recomendo usar. Só um dica. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste trecho:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="title">Pacientes</th>
       <th class="title">Como estou?</th>
       <th class="title">Administrar Paciente</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="title">Pacientes</th>
       <th class="title">Como estou?</th>
       <th class="title" colspan="3">Administrar Paciente</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Adicionar a colspan para que ela faça uma mesclagem das colunas e deixe na mesma linha os demais.

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar uma mesma coluna para as imagens. Pois há 3 headers `th` e há 5 colunas `td`, reduza para 3 colunas `td` :

```
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="title">Pacientes</th>
           <th class="title">Como estou?</th>
           <th class="title">Administrar Paciente</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
           <td><?=$linha['name']?></td>
           <td> <?=$$linnha['item_key']?> </td>
           <td> <a href="viewPatient.html" id="viewPatient"> <img id="viewPatientIcon" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/eye-outline.png" alt="eye icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a>           
             <a href="editPatient.html" id="editPatient"> <img id="editPatientIcon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/software-menu-icons/256/SoftwareIcons-68-512.png" alt="pen icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> 
             <a href="deletePatient" id="deletePatient"> <img id="deletePatientIcon" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-coloricon/21/19-512.png" alt="delete icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```